# SQL - Convert Datetime format

Tags: mysql, datetime-format

I try to change my format Datetime on MySQL

T got a table historic with some columns and some all them have this format DATETIME :

```
JJ/MM/AAAA HH:MM
```

I need to change to :

```
AAAA-MM-JJ HH:MM:SS
```

I don't have the variable for SS I would like to take 00.

Example

```
01/12/2012 12:23 > 2012-12-01 12:23:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You need to use Format Function for that

For above you can use

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT([YOURCOLUMNNAME],'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') from [YOURTABLENAME];
```

For all the conversion you can refer to.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Note that this format string will return 12hrs time. You might want to use `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s` to preserve 24hrs values.

Answer (score 4):

use **[date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)** function

Try below:

```
  SELECT  date_format(columnname,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') as yourdate FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the posted answers will work, as your data won't be recognized as a date.
Use string conversion instead:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = CONCAT(SUBSTR(columnname,7,4),'-',SUBSTR(columnname,4,2),'-',SUBSTR(columnname,1,2),SUBSTR(columname,11),':00');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is true if he has a varchar (or text) column type. But if the column is a DATETIME type (as specified in the question) it will recognized. In this case better see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636152/mysql-how-to-parse-a-string-value-to-datetime-format-inside-an-insert-statemen and [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function