# MySQL - How to parse a string value to DATETIME format inside an INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, datetime, insert

I have a `MySQL database`, with a column that is date type `DATETIME`.

I am getting a string value for a date / time from an external application. That string value looks like this:

```
'5/15/2012 8:06:26 AM'
```

MySQL throws an error on the INSERT: `"Error. Incorrect datetime value"`. My workaround was to change the column type to `VARCHAR`, which works, but I really need the data as a proper Date & Time for future use.

I researched accepted formatting for `MySQL DATETIME` values, and found that `MySQL` wants the `DATETIME` format as `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`.

I can't change the external application to reformat the date / time string in a format, so my only chance is to deal with it.

What I need to do, I think, is parse the existing string, using `MySQL syntax`, inside of my `INSERT` statement, but I'm not sure how to do that. I have some idea that I need to use a `SELECT` clause, perhaps `STR_TO_DATE`, somehow in combination with my INSERT statement.

Here is my current INSERT statement. I removed the other fields that are not causing a problem, just to make the example clean.

```
INSERT INTO tblInquiry (fldInquiryReceivedDateTime) VALUES ('5/15/2012 8:06:26')
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to parse the string that you're attempting to insert:

```
INSERT INTO tblInquiry (fldInquiryReceivedDateTime) VALUES
  (STR_TO_DATE('5/15/2012 8:06:26 AM', '%c/%e/%Y %r'))
```

Comment: is there a way to include a SWITCH that accommodates different formats?

Comment: It appears that `STR_TO_DATE('2/15/2017 05:16:56 PM','%m/%d/%Y %r')` format works as well... +1 Nice suggestion Mr, Eggnog!!