# How To Make More Than One html Player

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have created an audio player using html,css and java script. It works fine.But now i want to add number of player in a single page. Now when i play any player which plays the first player only.How can make it to play respectively..?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i am using mysql databsae

Comment: hint FROM_UNIXTIME(date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - How to parse a string value to DATETIME format inside an INSERT statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636152/mysql-how-to-parse-a-string-value-to-datetime-format-inside-an-insert-statemen)

Comment: UPDATE `some_table`
SET `timestamp_col` = `datetime_col`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
alter table test.tt2 add (Tdate datetime);
update test.tt2 set Tdate= STR_TO_DATE([Varchar Column Name], '%m/%d/%Y %k:%i');
alter table test.tt2 drop [Varchar Column Name];
```