# convert string to datetime in my sql

Tags: mysql

I want to convert the string `"2017-03-13T14:39:00.000"` into datetime format in my sql select query.

After converting it, I have to compare this with another date. So I'm expecting the converted datetime should be compatible with comparison  operators (< and >).

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me you should have stored the date as a DateTime column in the first place. Is it to late to fix that error rather than fiddle with the issue after the fact

Comment: Maybe google: `[mysql convert string to datetime]`.  first hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636152/mysql-how-to-parse-a-string-value-to-datetime-format-inside-an-insert-statemen fourth hit: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 14):

You might want to look at the STR_TO_DATE() function of mysql.

**Example (added)**

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2017-03-13T14:39:01.123','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f');
```

This is my result

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                        
| STR_TO_DATE('2017-03-13T14:39:01.123','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%f') |                                                                                        
+---------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                        
| 2017-03-13 14:39:01.123000                                    |                                                                                        
+---------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                        
1 row in set (0,00 sec)                                                                                                                                  
mysql>
```

Comment: A comment, but definitely not an answer

Comment: See edited answer. My Answer was right. Why should I answer questions in order to risk unfounded critics

Comment: STR_TO_DATE('31-07-2021 05:37 PM','%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p') one more example