# converting date and time to mysql datetime format

Tags: mysql

Currently, we are trying to convert: 'Wed, 13 Jun 2018 09:34:36' format to MySQL datetime format.

What would be a good approach for this? We have tried `cast()`

Comment: MySQL has a [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - How to parse a string value to DATETIME format inside an INSERT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636152/mysql-how-to-parse-a-string-value-to-datetime-format-inside-an-insert-statemen)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('13-Jun-2018 09:34:36', '%d-%M-%Y %h:%i:%s')
```

In python, I removed the first part and ending that was not needed.