# Converting a text timestamp to a datetime for all rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I imported data and a schema from an XML file into MySQL. I've got the following columns in quite a few tables:

```
DateStart     tinytext
DateEnd       tinytext
```

The format of this looks like a timestamp, ie. `2006-06-01T00:00:00-05:00`
Some of these values are also `null`. I need a way to convert this `tinytext` timestamp into a normal MySQL `datetime` but I am unsure how.

I tried to create a new column `my_date_time` that was a `datetime` type and tried converting each value like so:

```
UPDATE table SET my_date_time = str_to_date(DateStart, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '2006-09-01T00:00:00-05:00' for column 'DateStart' at row 1
```

How should I go about converting all the values in all of the rows for these columns?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636152/mysql-how-to-parse-a-string-value-to-datetime-format-inside-an-insert-statemen - your format string doesn't match the format of your date, but it looks like it's going to get more complicated than that, because it looks like `str_to_date` doesn't include a mechanism to parse the timezone in that format.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new field:

```
SELECT
  DateStart,
  DateEnd,
  CAST(DateStart AS DATETIME) AS my_date_time
FROM [your_table]
```

Or you can add a new column to your table using:

```
UPDATE [your_table] SET my_date_time = CAST(DateStart AS DATETIME);
```

You can cast as `DATE` instead of `DATETIME` if you only want the date.

This won't take care of the timezone though.

If you have values with different timezones you can use:

```
UPDATE [your_table] SET my_date_time = DATE_ADD(CAST('2006-09-01T00:00:00-05:00' AS DATETIME), INTERVAL CAST(substr('2006-09-01T00:00:00-05:00',20,3) AS SIGNED) HOUR);
```

This will work only if all the changes in time zones are complete hours (and not half hours).

Hope it helps