# Mysql Select record from now to next 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, datetime

Hello there i am creating a function in wordpress and i need to get records beetween now and next 7 days. i have tried few queries.but couldn't get the result.

```
SELECT * from wp_postmeta where wp_postmeta.meta_key = '__rp_order_date';
```

The query above returns

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key        | meta_value
--------+---------+-----------------+-------------------
7023    | 2979    | __rp_order_date | 2018-03-26 12:00 AM
```

but when i filter by date it doesn't display any records.

method 1

```
SELECT * from wp_postmeta where wp_postmeta.meta_key = '__rp_order_date' and date(wp_postmeta.meta_value) BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

method 2

```
SELECT * from wp_postmeta where wp_postmeta.meta_key = '__rp_order_date' and date(wp_postmeta.meta_value) <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

My actual intention is to execute this code,which also displays nothing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id,wp_posts.post_status,wp_postmeta.meta_value as delivery_date from wp_woocommerce_order_items 
INNER JOIN wp_posts on wp_posts.ID = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id 
where wp_posts.post_status='wc-processing' and wp_postmeta.meta_key = '__rp_order_date' and DATE(wp_postmeta.meta_value) <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

I couldn't figure it out, thanks in advance.

Comment: that's because you stored that `2018-03-26 12:00 AM` as a string, rather than making that column a DATETIME type, given if that is your actual stored value..

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Actually the value stored by a plugin which i have no control to , is there is any way i can convert the format in the query?thanks

Comment: You would need to format it then https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205873/sql-convert-datetime-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Place of
`date(wp_postmeta.meta_value)` Use `STR_TO_DATE(wp_postmeta.meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d')`

You Can use like this also, You have to CONCAT `:00` in your time to convert `varchar` to `datetime`

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '__rp_order_date' 
AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(wp_postmeta.meta_value,1,16),':00 ',SUBSTRING(wp_postmeta.meta_value,18,2)),'%Y-%m-%d %r') 
BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/748788/9

Comment: it works,STR_TO_DATE(wp_postmeta.meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 DAY),thanks.

Comment: Welcome !! @RyVan

Comment: You can check Another method also

Comment: i can totally ignore the time since i only need dates,so the first solutions serves better,but nice query.tanx